# Hibernate DateTime between two columns

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to find entries in hibernate based on a DateTime object where a startDate column is less than the DateTime and an endDate column is greater than the DateTime.  I am attempting this using the code below

```
    DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(FinancialEventGroup.class);
    crit.add(Property.forName("groupPeriodStart").lt(eventDate));
    crit.add(Property.forName("groupPeriodEnd").gt(eventDate));
```

But this is returning null when it should not.  Any suggestions?  Other DO access methods are working so this is not an issue with hibernate configuration I suspect it is an issue with the detached criteria setup

edit: I figured out my issue in part because of the help below.  I am facing another issue where I want the eventDate to be less than the groupPeriodEnd ONLY IF the group period end is not empty (i.e. if this is an open period that has not ended).  Is there an XOR/either restriction in hibernate?  Is there a way to do this or do I just have to filter the results?

Comment: Can you use normal HPQL query insted of Criteria? It would look something like `"SELECT feg FROM FinancialEventGroup feg  WHERE feg.groupPeriodStart < :event AND feg.gropPeriodEnd > :event"

Comment: did you try generated sql in your sqldeveloper ide?

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria as it is will always produce query that returns 0 records. Regardless of data type, one field in the table cannot be greater than certain value and less than it at the same time... You probably want to use `le` or `ge` instead of `lt`/`gt`...

Answer (score 0):

Use Restrictions instead of property and also ge/le(>= / <=)

```
 DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(FinancialEventGroup.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.le("groupPeriodStart",eventDate);
    crit.add(Restrictions.ge("groupPeriodEnd",eventDate);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be

    crit.add(Restrictions.ge("groupPeriodStart",eventDate);
    crit.add(Restrictions.le("groupPeriodEnd",eventDate);

if I want the result to be after the start date and before the end date?